# jQuery Mobile existing action bar implementations?

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if there are working action bar implementations for the jQuery Mobile library. Thanks!

Comment: CLOSED? and yet this page comes up #3 on google when i search for jquery action bar. guess i'll keep looking .......

Comment: I have this same problem. I don't know why this was closed. I can't find any information on building android style action bars (specifically the "Action overflow" menu) using jQuery mobile.